# std::string_view on temporary string - catch by ASan

Tags: c++, c++17, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

This is dangling pointer|reference example:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

std::string foo() {
    return "test";
}

int main() {
    std::string_view bar = foo(); // bar is pointed to destructed string
    std::cout << bar << std::endl;
}
```

Address sanitizer cannot catch it, at least with default options.
Is it possible to catch such errors with address sanitizer?

UPD.

Reported this bug:

- https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35285
- https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/879

Comment: couldnt find anything either, only return by stack address detections, not destructed temporary return values.

Answer (score 3):

My guess (you haven't provided compiler version) is that `operator <<` is implemented externally so Asan can't sanitize it and detect error (unless you rebuild libstdc++ with Asan). Here's what I get with my GCC 6.2 (I slightly modified repro as I don't have access to `c++1z`):

```
  call    operator delete(void*)
.L17:
  movq    %rbx, %rsi
  movl    std::cout, %edi
  call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
  call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
```

Comment: Replace `std::cout << bar` with, for example, `std::string bar2 = bar;`.

Comment: @vladon This is very different situation. It works for me (i.e. reports `heap-use-after-free`) as long as string is longer than 16 chars. For shorter string you get SSO i.e. data is kept on stack so Asan can no longer detect heap errors.